# How to use NFC with RFID tags/chips

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, nfc

When I bought my Samsung Galaxy SIII, there was a big buzz about the new phones
on the market supporting NFC (Near-Field Communications). However, given that
Blutooth exchange of files and even the somewhat more powerful Wi-Fi Direct
protocols were already available to allow files to be exchange, it seems
to me that yet another technology (NFC), when used to transfer files,
doesn't add much to what was already available.

Hence, the true value of NFC should be its ability to read RFID (Radio-Frequency
Identification) tags. However, I have not been able to find any of these devices
anywhere, and I'm not sure if it's because these are less used abroad where I am
living or not. So, where can I find these devices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NFC tags are one type of RFID tags. NFC is a protocol for RFID, which can be understand by more and more devices.
You can buy NFC tags on amazon or other websites.

What can I do with that tags?
You can trigger something when you touch your phone to that tag. For example a NFC tag in your car which turns on Bluetooth, mutes your phone and turns off the lock screen. Then you can put the tag anywhere in your car and when you touch it your phone will be in your "car-mode"
However this requires some apps to work. For example 'Trigger' (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher) or 'NFC Tasks' are great apps for this purpose.

Comment: OK. So I can buy [whole sets of NFC tags from Amazon](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=NFC+tag) and other sellers. And I can then write information to and read information from these tags. However, my question persists: why would I want to do this? Even if I placed these stickers in various places, why would this be useful? Thanks.

Comment: There are very useful apps like Trigger (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jwsoft.nfcactionlauncher). They can trigger different things if you attach a configured NFC Tag. (WiFi on/off, audio on/off, wake on lan for computers, and much more). I'am using "NFC Tasks" for a while and i am really happy with that.

Comment: I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you for elaborating your answer. However, I'm still a bit puzzled. For simply triggering actions related to turning various type of network connectivity on or off, wouldn't it be just as easy to tap an icon somewhere on the phone? For instance, the Samsung Galaxy SIII has some nice network connectivity icons easily accessible at the top of the notifications list. With NFC, to swipe the phone next to the NFC tag seems to me like it takes just as much effort. There sure must be some more compelling uses of NFC. Perhaps you can elaborate further. Thanks.

Comment: Simply, you can save a specified amount of bytes (max. 1KB on some NFC tags; usually around 150B) of data on a NFC tag. Then you can do what you want with that data. So it is possible to store WiFi credentials on a NFC tag and people in a hotel for example can simply touch their phone to that tag and get WiFi. Or, there are some ways to use a NFC tag to bypass your lockscreen in android, which is very useful cause you don't need a PIN or a password anymore. (But this requires a rooted phone and Xposed)

Comment: OK, perhaps this is somewhat more useful. The NFC tag can be used to store credentials, and transmit those credentials to nearby smartphones which would otherwise have to obtain and then input such information manually. But if only 150B are stored on NFC tags (this is almost as short as the 120B length of an SMS message!), how can there be enough information even to tell the phone what app to use to read the data? Seems like the data would have to be packed quite tightly.

Comment: The apps do register their own protocols in android. So if there is a trigger app, it could have the trigger:// prefix (like http:// for websites etc). Then, when a tag is attached to the phone, android decides which app to use for this data. For common things like coordinates or address book entries there are predefined formats how they have to be stored on the tag.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I entered "trigger://" in Google but could not find any results with this kind of URL you mention. Could you please provide a pointer? Thanks.

Comment: This trigger:// was only an example for the possibilities to bind an app to a specified protocol.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Anyways, I can see that the higher-end NFC tags carrying 1KB of information should be able to carry enough information to do some pretty nifty stuff. Thank you for your answers.